# Getting PID of process in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pid

I am writing one shell script and I want to get PID of one process with name as "ABCD". What i did was :

```
process_id=`/bin/ps -fu $USER|grep "ABCD"|awk '{print $2}'`
```

This gets PID of two processes i.e. of process ABCD and the GREP command itself what if I don't want to get PID of GREP executed and I want PID only of ABCD process?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just grep away grep itself!

```
process_id=`/bin/ps -fu $USER| grep "ABCD" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Thanks for quick Answer.It worked.Also what if i dont want PID of script which is executing this. Because my script also contains ABCD

Comment: Surely you can think of something to "grep away" again, as the PID of your script, which should be available via the `$$` variable

Comment: A trick for avoiding the 2nd grep is to give `grep` a regular expression that matches the same thing, but appears different on the command line: `... | grep "[A]BCD" | awk ...`.

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried to use `pidof ABCD`  ?

Comment: this is actually a better answer for most cases :)

Comment: Or `pgrep ABCD`

Comment: The `pidof` command does not behave the same on every Linux distribution. So using `pidof` is not a good solution. It is also necessary to distinguish between the version of `ps` included in BusyBox - in lightweight Linux distributions (for example in a set-top box) and another `ps`, which is designed for full-fledged Linux. In the BusyBox version of the `ps` command, almost no arguments / switches work. In the case of BusyBox, the `ps` command is used a little differently. You have to be careful.

Answer (score 9):

It's very straight forward. *ABCD* should be replaced by your process name.

```
#!/bin/bash

processId=$(ps -ef | grep 'ABCD' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ printf $2 }')
echo $processId
```

Sometimes you need to replace *ABCD* by software name. Example - if you run a java program like `java -jar TestJar.jar &` then you need to replace *ABCD* by *TestJar.jar*.

Answer (score 4):

ps has an option for that:

```
process_id=`/bin/ps -C ABCD -o pid=`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do away with `grep` and use only `awk`.
Use `awk`'s [expression matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Expression-Patterns.html) to match the process name but not itself.

```
/bin/ps -fu $USER | awk '/ABCD/ && !/awk/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to grep the pid of a particular process & echo `$b` to print pid of any running process:

```
b=`ps -ef | grep [A]BCD | awk '{ printf $2 }'`
echo $b
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to do this.

```
top -n 1 | grep "@#" | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

`ps | pgrep ABCD`

You can try the above command to return the process id of the ABCD process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'pgrep #prog_name' instead and it shall return prog_name PID directly.